# Are Death Race 2 and the Alien franchise connected?

Tags: alien, death-race-2

Both films have a large corporation called the Wayland corporation which seems to be all controlling, in Alien they're a large haulage/terraforming company. In Death Race they run private prisons.

Are these set in the same universe? Is this naming a coincidence or are there some production nods to the naming?

Comment: Look's like a homage but still want to know if there something else.

Comment: I found nothing connecting the two. Nothing in the arena of production or writing. The name does not seem to appear in *Alien* (it is just called "The Company"), but appears in *Aliens* as "Weland/Yutani Corp". Anyway, maybe someone else has some better information, and thus why I dropped it as a comment instead of an answer.

Comment: The film was produced by [Paul W.S. Anderson](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0027271/) who is not only responsible for __Death Race 1__, but also for __Alien vs. Predator__. - Hey, if Joss Whedon's __Firefly__ can [share a universe](http://firefly.wikia.com/wiki/Weyland-Yutani) with the _Alien_ franchise, why not _Death Race?_

Comment: @Oliver_C That *Paul W.S. Anderson* connection seems like likely possibility (/answer).

Comment: they are connected by the Weland company, which is the answer, but the answer should be written by @Oliver_C

Comment: Just to clarify, my previous comment was tongue-in-cheek. Sometimes a reference is just meant as in-joke, e.g. the _Millenium Falcon_ [appearing in](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Battle_of_Sector_001#Visualization) _Star Trek: First Contact_.

Comment: @Oliver_C Well, then it's just an in-joke, so what, an in-joke is as reasonable a connection as anything else and *Paul W. S. Anderson* might still be the reason for this in-joke.

Comment: @ChristianRau - An _in-joke_ doesn't proof a _shared universe_, because sometimes is just a gag, a nod, a tribute,... - I don't think Paul W.S. Anderson owns the rights to the Alien-franchise, so unless he got approval, this "Weyland" is probably not _officially_ part of the Alien-universe.

Comment: @Oliver_C I wasn't saying it prooves a shared universe, rather on the contrary. In fact I guess everything but an in-joke would probably be unreasonable plot-extrapolation and interpreting stuff into things that are not meant to mean much more than an in-joke. I was just saying that an in-joke would have been as valid and possible an answer to this question as any other more elaborate connection, like a shared universe. Nothing else is the accepted and up-voted (by me at least) answer saying.

Comment: In Alien 3, the prison is also maintained by the Weyland Corp. Love these references.

Comment: They mention Weyland corporation in Death Race 2, that they scrap the cars and melt them down for weapons and sell for cheap...
Could be a link? Would be an interesting concept!

Comment: Yes. It's just too awesome to not be part of the same universe.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'd say they may be loosely connected. Paul W.S. Anderson was the producer on *Death Race 2*, *Death Race*, and *Alien vs. Predator*. It's likely that including Weyland Corporation in *Death Race 2* was an homage or in-joke, but there's nothing to say that it's not the same company (and therefore the films share the same universe).

It's also worth noting that Weyland-Yutani appears briefly in both *Firefly* and *Angel*. These shows were created by Joss Whedon, who also wrote *Alien: Resurrection*. Again, this is also probably an in-joke or Easter Egg, but worth mentioning.

Weyland-Yutani also appears in numerous other media, as in-jokes or visual references. The only one of these I can cite here is *Red Dwarf*, but you can see visual references to the Alien franchise all over the place.

**References**

Weyland-Yutani was a client of Wolfram & Hart in *Angel* - [http://home.vicnet.net.au/~kwgow/cross_key.pdf](http://web.archive.org/web/20121013175513/http://home.vicnet.net.au/~kwgow/cross_key.pdf)

In the opening episode of Firefly, one of the characters fires a turret manufactured by Welyand-Yutani - http://firefly.wikia.com/wiki/Weyland-Yutani

A Weyland-Yutani ship appears in the spaceship graveyard in the *Red Dwarf* episode *Psirens* - [http://home.vicnet.net.au/~kwgow/cross_key.pdf](http://web.archive.org/web/20121013175513/http://home.vicnet.net.au/~kwgow/cross_key.pdf)

It's also worth noting that the OP is not the first person to spot the connection. Empire Magazine's article *[The Most Evil Movie Corporations](http://www.empireonline.com/features/evil-movie-corporations/)* specifically states one of Weyland-Yutani's corporate activities as "operate privately-owned prisons with scant regard for the health or rehabilitation of inmates."